# Ajax request is sent muliple times because button is inside multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code:

```
$('div').on('click', '#my_btn',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var btn = $(this);
    $.post(...)
    .done(function(data){
        btn.replaceWith("<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" id=\"my_btn\">Changed!</button>");
    });
});
```

However, this code sends post request multiple times because of
 `$('div').on('click', '#my_btn',function(e){` ..

This could easily be resolved by using single `$('#my_btn').click()..` , but since I replacing dom using jquery `replaceWith` this code would work only once(tested). So, what should I do to send ajax only once and also make click function work for new buttons?

Comment: listen an upper level `$('body').on('click', '#my_btn',function(e){})`

Comment: @MysterX amazing. It works! Thanks. I hadn't thought about it before.